# Convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1+n)^n}{n!}x^n $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1+n)^n}{n!}x^n $$ Now the ratio test shows that the given power series converges absolutely $|x|< 1/e$ and diverges for $|x|>1/e$. But all the tests I know(Raabe's test) are failing at $|x|=1/e$.  Any help will be highly apprecieated.

Comment: I suppose that you mean $\lvert x\rvert=\frac1e$.

Comment: For $x=\frac 1 e$ the series behaves like $\sum \frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ as seen from Stirling's formula.

Comment: I don't want to use stirling's formula :)

Comment: To prove that it converges or not it is always good to see if you can bound it, either from below or from above. Stirling's formula provides the nice tight bounds that you need here. You may be able to come up with a different method but for that purpose I don't see the point :)

Answer (score 0):

For $x=\frac 1 e$ we have

$$\frac{(1+n)^n}{n!e^n}$$

and using Stirling's approximation $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ we have

$$\frac{(1+n)^n}{e^nn!}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

then recall that by Bernoulli

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\ge 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Call $a_n=\frac{(1+n)^n}{n!}x^n$. If you use Raabe's test for $x=\frac1e$, you obtain $$\frac{(1+n)^n(n+1)!e}{(2+n)^{n+1}n!}n-n=en\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{-n-1}-n=$$

Substitute $t=\frac1{n+1}$ $$=\left(\frac{e}{t}-e\right)(1+t)^{-1/t}-\frac1t+1=\frac{e(1+t)^{-1/t}-1}{t}+1-e(1+t)^{-1/t}$$

And you should recognize, among the terms up there, the incremental ratio at $0$ of the continuous function $$f(t)=\begin{cases}e(1+t)^{-1/t}&\text{if }t>-1\land t\ne 0\\ 1&\text{if }t=0\end{cases}$$ which has derivative $$f'(t)=\begin{cases}e\left(\frac{\ln(1+t)-t}{t^2}+\frac{\ln(1+t)}t\right)(1+t)^{-\frac1t-1}&\text{if }t>-1\land t\ne 0\\ \frac 1{2}&\text{if }t=0\end{cases}$$

So $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e(1+t)^{-1/t}-1}{t}+1-e(1+t)^{-1/t}=f'(0)+1-f(0)=\frac12$$

And so the series is divergent for $x=\frac1e$.

The previous estimate on $n\frac{a_n(1/e)}{a_{n+1}(1/e)}-n=n\left\lvert \frac{a_n(-1/e)}{a_{n+1}(-1/e)}\right\rvert-n$ implies that eventually $$\left\lvert \frac{a_n(-1/e)}{a_{n+1}(-1/e)}\right\rvert\ge 1+\frac1{4n}>1$$

and thus that $\lvert a_{n}(-1/e)\rvert> \lvert a_{n+1}(-1/e)\rvert$ eventually. Therefore, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n(-1/e)$ converges by Leibniz.